# PHP : Required Post Params is missing

Tags: php, python, html, json

I am running a website using Python and PHP. Every change has been done and there are no errors. I am not able to Login ,But it shows 200 status code.`

Here is my login.php:

```
<?php
include_once '../config/database.php';
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

if(!empty($_POST["Username"]) && !empty($_POST["password"])  ) {
    $Username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim($_POST["Username"]));
    $password =mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, trim( $_POST["password"]));

    $passwordkey = md5( $password );
    $password_e=crypt("obsfebs",$passwordkey);
    $loginquery = "SELECT * FROM `obsfebs_admin` WHERE Username='$Username' AND password='$password_e'";
    $adminquery = mysqli_query($conn, $loginquery);
    $admin = mysqli_num_rows($adminquery);
    if($admin > 0){

        $data["status"] = 1;
        $data["message"] = "Successfully LoggedIn ";
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
    else{
        $data["status"] = 2;
        $data["message"] = "Username or password is wrong !!! ";
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
}else {
    // required post params is missing
    $data["status"] = 0;
    $data["message"] = "Required parameters mobile or password is missing!";
    $data["details"] = "";
    echo json_encode($data);
}
?>
```

Here is my views.py:

```
def user_login(request):
    datas= {'log':False}
    if request.method == "POST":
        usern=request.POST.get('Username')
        passw=request.POST.get('password')
        passw=requests.post(url='http://www.onebookingsystem.com/productionApi/API/Admin/login.php')
        response = requests.post(url='http://www.onebookingsystem.com/productionApi/API/Admin/login.php',data={"Username":usern,"password":passw})
        json_data = response.json()
```

I am not getting any error. But when i enter username and password, it is not Login. It is telling "Required post params is missing".

Comment: ***You really shouldn't use [MD5 password hashes](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure)*** and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. Make sure  you [don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: Aside from the other issues in your code that have been covered, a 200 status code is what is expected from a successful completion of a request! **It literally means there is no error**.

Comment: Plus, why are you using both PHP and Python? How are they connected together?

Comment: And why is your view code making _two_ POST requests to the same API endpoint, the first time sending no data at all? Presumably that is where the error message stems from? (Although the _exact_ error message you say you are getting, does not seem to be output by your PHP code either, the ones in there are all phrased slightly different.)

Comment: @DanielRoseman - It looks like the PHP part is an API endpoint which the python code consumes.

Comment: In your Python code, it seems like you're trying to use the response from the first post request (**where the post params are missing**) as the password for the second request? That doesn't really make much sense.